# Delete SQL statement for MSACCESS DB

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am attempting to run a delete statement for an MS Access DB and i receive an error of "Index out of Range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection".

Here is my delete button code:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    ' This is our DELETE Statement. To be sure we delete the correct record and not all of   
    ' them.  
    ' We use the WHERE to be sure only that record that the user has selected is deleted.  
    Dim con1 As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Redirection\fakeout\Desktop\AccessDBs\MovieCatalog.mdb")
    Dim sqldelete As String
    sqldelete = "DELETE * FROM Table1 WHERE ID='" & dgvList.CurrentRow.Cells(7).Value.ToString & "'"
    ' This is our DataAdapter. This executes our SQL Statement above against the Database  
    ' we defined in the Connection String  
    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(sqldelete, con1)
    ' Gets the records from the table and fills our adapter with those.  
    Dim dt As New DataTable("Table1")
    adapter.Fill(dt)
    ' Assigns the edited DataSource on the DataGridView and the refreshes the   
    ' view to ensure everything is up to date in real time.  
    dgvList.DataSource = dt
    ' This is a Sub in Module 1 to refresh the DataGridView when information is added,  
    '  updated, or deleted.  
    RefreshDGV()
End Sub
```

I Open my connection on my form load:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    sSql = "SELECT ID, Title, YearofFilm, Description, Field1 FROM Table1"
    LoadDS(sSql)
    FillGrid()
End Sub

Private Sub LoadDS(ByVal sSQL As String)
    Try
        Dim cnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Redirection\fake\Desktop\AccessDBs\MovieCatalog.mdb"
        'Open Connection.
        Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(cnString)

        'Set the DataAdapter's query.
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sSQL, conn)
        ds = New DataSet()

        ' Fill the DataSet.
        da.Fill(ds, "Items")

        ' Set the source table.
        dtSource = ds.Tables("Items")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

How should i combine that in my delete function?

Comment: (a) The syntax is `DELETE FROM`, not `DELETE * FROM`. (b) You didn't say which line gives the error, but guessing from the error, I suspect `dgvList.CurrentRow.Cells(7)` should be `dgvList.CurrentRow.Cells(6)`. (c) As LarsTech pointed out, you should really be using SQL parameters for the query.

Comment: i am getting the error on th sqldelete line. I changed it and removed the * and changed 7 to 6. same error

Comment: You should check to see how many rows `dgvList.CurrentRow` has. It might not be the row you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the delete command to the database with an OleDbCommand object. You are trying to use objects that retrieve data (i.e. the DataAdapter and DataTable).

```
Using con1 As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Redirection\fakeout\Desktop\AccessDBs\MovieCatalog.mdb")

        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("DELETE * FROM Table1 WHERE ID='" & dgvList.CurrentRow.Cells(7).Value.ToString & "'", con1)

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End Using

    End Using
```

Comment: You should help the OP use Parameters to avoid SQL injection.  Your connection isn't open either.

Comment: added more detail to my post.  Your above solution gave me same error.